# How to retrieve the prefab clone into the script when it is instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create level prograss bar, here is the script to fill the Slider along with ball when its moving towards finish line , here finish line is prefab clone which is randomly instantiated at different position. but as expected finishTransform using position(0, 0, 0) from prefab not from the clone. how can i retrieve the clone into the script when it is instantiated? here is the Progressbar Script :

```
[SerializeField] Transform ballTransform;
 [SerializeField] Transform finishTransform;
 [SerializeField] Slider slider;

 float maxDistance;



 void Start()
 {
     maxDistance = getDistance();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (ballTransform.position.z <= maxDistance && ballTransform.position.z <= finishTransform.position.z)
     {
         float distance = 1 - (getDistance() / maxDistance);
         setProgress(distance);
     }
 }

 float getDistance()
 {

     return Vector3.Distance(ballTransform.position, finishTransform.position);
 }

 void setProgress(float p)
 {
     slider.value = p;
 }
```

Here is the Platform script where i instantiated the finish line

```
GameObject finalPlatformInstance = Instantiate(finalPlatform, transform);
     finalPlatformInstance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
```

Comment: Are we talking about Unity? What's the "Platform script"? what's spawnPosZ? what's "transform" in the Instantiate call? retrieve the clone to what script? You left out all the context from the question.

Comment: hi , yes i am talking about Unity, in Platform Script i have instantiated finish line at spawnPosZ (position where finish line instantiate in the scene) and i want to retrieve this clone to ProgressBar Script

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution.

```
public class PlatformSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject finalPlatform; // This get injected in the editor
   public GameObject finalPlatformInstance;

   void Awake()
   {
      finalPlatformInstance = Instantiate(finalPlatform, transform);
      finalPlatformInstance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, z);

      // TODO: add other logic...
   }
}

public class ProgressBar : MonoBehaviour
{
   private Platform platform;

   void Start()
   {
      platform = FindObjectOfType<PlatformSpawner>();
   }

   void Update()
   {
      // TODO: access it via "platform.finalPlatformInstance"
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i just added a tag when instantiating finalplatform and used that tag to find the object : GameObject finalPlatformInstance = Instantiate(finalPlatform, transform);
        finalPlatformInstance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
        finalPlatformInstance.transform.tag = "FinishLine"; used this Tag in progressbar script  to find the finishTransform . this works fine

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Happy Easter.

Comment: happy Easter :)